# prevent transform files from getting deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config-transform

I am working with an asp.net mvc web application that works with using web transform files to transform the web.config and other config files. This works very well.

An improvement I would like to make is that when the app gets deployed to an environment, all the transform files also get deployed eg. qa, dev, production etc.

In web transforms, is there any easy to stop this and ensure they don't get deployed?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Publish functionality in Visual Studio, this will only copy the transformed config file(s) to your target directory.  A simplified scenario would be to publish to a local folder and then copy the files from there to the environment where they will be used.

To get to the Publish interface you can right click in the menu section of the IDE and include the Web One Click Publish toolbar, or you can right click on the project you want to publish and click the Publish command from there. The toolbar gives you the flexibility of selecting which Publish profile you want to use.